# How to create a starting value in a random - Groovy Scripting

Tags: groovy, soapui

In groovy scripting for SOAP UI, if I wanted to output a random number between 1 - 999, how can I do this as I don't want to display the integer 0 or it will cause an error in my test. Below is the code I currently have which does 0-999.

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue('departureAirportId', String.valueOf((int)Math.random()*999))
```

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps if you add `1`, result will never be `0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be simple by adding 1.

`((int)((Math.random()*999)+1))`

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue('departureAirportId', String.valueOf(((int)((Math.random()*999)+1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

SoapUI also has [Apache lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html) library built-in. You could use something like:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue('departureAirportId', RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(3))
```

Note that this produces a 3-character string, so something like "1" will actually come out as "001".

Comment: It's been 4 years since this comment, it still works with SoapUI 5.5 - thanks